# Android 12 splash white background

Tags: android, splash-screen, beta, android-12

I was trying to add support to the Android 12 splash screen.
Here's my `v31/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">#FF3044</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#FF3044</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I am able to see a white screen after the new splash. That white screen is the `android:windowBackground` but if I tried to set it as `@null`, I am getting inverted splash at the place of the white screen.
How to remove that white background after the splash? Splash API was designed to replace windowBackground I guess.

App flow -> SplashActivity (with the mentioned theme) and then I pause the preDraw method using a ViewModel then navigate to another activity.

SplashActivity.kt - `onCreate()`

```
val content: View = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
    content.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
        object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                return if (viewModel.appInit()) {
                    navigateToHome()
                    content.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

HomeActivity doesn't have any theme. When I add `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/android:black</item>` in the Splash's theme, instead of the white screen, I'm getting the black one.

Comment: Do you see the color you assigned to the splash screen at all?
If yes, and if the white flash happens after, you might have another activity starting or you might set another theme.

It would help if you also share your Activity code.

Comment: Yeah, if I set windowsBackground to the above style, then I can see that color instead of white. I am able to see the splash background and icon too before that. Flow is like this - SplashActivity(with the mentioned theme) then I pause the preDraw method and navigate to another activity.

Comment: My guess is that the white flash the windowBackground of your second activity

Comment: No, that can't be because when I add windowsBackground as black to SplashActivity's theme, that replaces the white background.

Comment: You said that you navigate to a second activity. I think this second activity has the white background, unless you also set the same theme for the second activity.

Maybe paste your manifest.xml, and Activities' code to help us find the issue.

Comment: Updated the description. The second activity can't be the problem because on adding windowBackground item to Splash's theme, I'm able to replace the white background.

Comment: Thank you for the details. 
You return `true` after calling `navigateToHome()`, so your is app actually drawing the windowBackground of the SplashActivity before the HomeActivity is started.
Try to always return `false` in the SplashActivity's preDrawListener.

Comment: Tried after return `false` too, but not working... still getting the white background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234361/discussion-between-vadim-caen-and-tronku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning `true` and removing the `OnPreDrawListener` after requesting the navigation to your other activity, which indicates to the system that your current Activity is now ready to draw, but the next one is not yet visible, hence the flash you're seeing.

Simply always return `false` in the predraw listener and remove it in `onStop()`

Comment: can you also update the official doc? It asks us to remove the listener once the viewmodel is ready, before return false. Will that work? as we have removed the listener and then passing the false/true to it.

Comment: The documentation is valid when you don't navigate to another activity. There is no single way to handle the splash screen when navigating to another activity and ideally, this shouldn't happen to reduce the startup time.